# Metatable in Module Script not excetuting Roblox

Tags: oop, lua, roblox, metatable

so i made 2 module scripts

here's the code:

```
local base = {}
base.__index = base

base.Number = 5

function base:New()
local t = setmetatable({}, self)

 t.__index = t 
return t
end

 return base
```

second:

```
  local base = script.Parent.Base


 local child = require(base):New()

  return child
```

this one is normal script:

```
  local child = require(script.Parent.Child1)

   print(child.Number)
```

and i get this message after i try executing it

stack begin
script
'ServerScriptService.Script', Line 1
Stack End

it should've executed "5"
but its not working and i don't know why

Comment: What are `script.Parent.Child1` and `script.Parent.Base`? My first guess would be that require fails for the last script.

Answer (score 0):

In your Base class, you set the `__index` metamethod to the `base` object, then in the constructor you say `setmetatable({}, base)` these two lines mean that when someone asks for a property on the empty table, that it should be found on the `base` object instead. But they you overwrite that behavior by setting the `__index` metamethod again. This removes the relationship between the new object and its base class.

So to fix this, just remove that line in the constructor.

```
function base:New()
    local t = setmetatable({}, base)
    return t
end
```